# Atoms in our body

Tags: atoms, biophysics

Our body of course exchanges some atoms with environment every day however are there some of atoms which stay with us a life time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The atoms in the enamel of the teeth are not exchanged with the environment. Indeed, long after your death their isotopic composition can be used to tell [where you lived](http://www.wessexarch.co.uk/projects/amesbury/tests/oxygen_isotope.html) while your teeth were growing.

Comment: That's pretty amazing.